# How to set multiple figures with a specific margin between them

Tags: tables, floats

I have some figure results and I need to struct them according to the following shape.

in the first line, I will show two results (a) and (b), in between (a) images there is no margin and they are centered on the cells, as well as for (b) images 
and in the center, I want to set a remarkable margin to separate each result.

[image]

thank you

Code :

```
    \documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage{amsmath}
    \usepackage{algorithm}
    \usepackage[noend]{algpseudocode}
    \usepackage{array}
    \usepackage{multirow}
    \usepackage{booktabs}
    \usepackage{makecell}

    \usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
    \usepackage{adjustbox} 

    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \usepackage{lmodern}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage{caption}
    \usepackage{verbatim}

    \begin{document}


    \begin{figure}[h!]

    {\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0.8}
    \begin{center}   
    \begin{tabular}{cccccc}
    \includegraphics[width=2.5cm,height=2.2cm]{example-image-a} & \includegraphics[width=2.5cm,height=2.2cm]{example-image-a} & \includegraphics[width=2.5cm,height=2.2cm]{example-image-a}& \includegraphics[width=2.5cm,height=2.2cm]{example-image-a}& \includegraphics[width=2.5cm,height=2.2cm]{example-image-a} & \includegraphics[width=2.5cm,height=2.2cm]{example-image-a}\\
    \multicolumn{3}{c}{(a) }& \multicolumn{3}{c}{(b)}\\
    \includegraphics[width=2.5cm,height=2.2cm]{example-image-b}& \includegraphics[width=2.5cm,height=2.2cm]{example-image-b}& \includegraphics[width=2.5cm,height=2.2cm]{example-image-b}& \includegraphics[width=2.5cm,height=2.2cm]{example-image-b}& \includegraphics[width=2.5cm,height=2.2cm]{example-image-b} & \includegraphics[width=2.5cm,height=2.2cm]{example-image-b}\\
    \multicolumn{3}{c}{(c) } & \multicolumn{3}{c}{(d) }\\
    \includegraphics[width=2.5cm,height=2.2cm]{example-image-c}& \includegraphics[width=2.5cm,height=2.2cm]{example-image-c}& \includegraphics[width=2.5cm,height=2.2cm]{example-image-c}& \includegraphics[width=2.5cm,height=2.2cm]{example-image-c}& \includegraphics[width=2.5cm,height=2.2cm]{example-image-c} & \includegraphics[width=2.5cm,height=2.2cm]{example-image-c}\\
    \multicolumn{3}{c}{(e) } & \multicolumn{3}{c}{(f) }\\
    \end{tabular}
    \end{center}
    }
    \caption{ results .} \label{fig:figure_A}
    \end{figure}    

    \end{document}
```

Comment: can you make a MWE?

Comment: do you mean a Minimal Working Example ?

Comment: Yes, please. :)

Comment: okay i will do it

Comment: cool, that will be very helpful. @samcarter Could you just solve this with subfigures or nested subfigures (because of the captions) and then set the horizontal spaces with `\hspace{val}` and `\hfil` and `~` and `\newline`s? I mean, that's what I would try.

Comment: I need to set images in the center, and a small margin between them and in the center a large margin

Comment: @thymaro Should be doable with subfigures. I decided to go the easy road and just adjust the code a bit, but please feel free to add an answer yourself!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer keeps your general approach to use a table, but simplifies it a bit:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage[noend]{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{makecell}

\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{adjustbox} 

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{verbatim}

\begin{document}


\begin{figure}[htbp]
    \centering
  \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0.8}
    \begin{tabular}{ccc}
        \includegraphics[width=.145\textwidth]{example-image-a} 
        \includegraphics[width=.145\textwidth]{example-image-a} 
        \includegraphics[width=.145\textwidth]{example-image-a}&&
        \includegraphics[width=.145\textwidth]{example-image-a}
        \includegraphics[width=.145\textwidth]{example-image-a}
        \includegraphics[width=.145\textwidth]{example-image-a}\\
        (a) & & (b)\\
        \includegraphics[width=.145\textwidth]{example-image-a} 
        \includegraphics[width=.145\textwidth]{example-image-a} 
        \includegraphics[width=.145\textwidth]{example-image-a}&&
        \includegraphics[width=.145\textwidth]{example-image-a}
        \includegraphics[width=.145\textwidth]{example-image-a}
        \includegraphics[width=.145\textwidth]{example-image-a}\\
        (c) & & (d)\\
        \includegraphics[width=.145\textwidth]{example-image-a} 
        \includegraphics[width=.145\textwidth]{example-image-a} 
        \includegraphics[width=.145\textwidth]{example-image-a}&&
        \includegraphics[width=.145\textwidth]{example-image-a}
        \includegraphics[width=.145\textwidth]{example-image-a}
        \includegraphics[width=.145\textwidth]{example-image-a}\\
        (e) & & (f)\\
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{results.}
    \label{fig:figure_A}
\end{figure}    

\end{document}
```

[image]

*(Please only specify either the width or the height of an image, if you specify both, it will be distorted)*

Comment: (Please only specify either the width or the height of an image, if you specify both, it will be distorted) @ need to set the width and the height both of them

Comment: @azdoud Don't set both, this will destroy the aspect ratio of your images.

Comment: @azdoud Or you could add the optional parameter `keepaspectratio`, which will reduce the size of the figure in one direction. To avoid distortion, edit the images externally and make sure they have the correct aspect ratio, then include them in your document.